# High CPU utilization using f1-micro instance

Tags: google-app-engine

I am running a site on App Engine (managed VM). It is currently running on f1-micro instances.

The Cloud platform Console reports that CPU utilization is ~40%. I became a little suspicious because the site is receiving practically zero traffic. Is this normal for an idle golang app on a f1-micro instance?

I logged onto the actual instance and "top" reports CPU utilization ~2%.

What gives? Why is "top" saying something different than the Console?

Comment: serverfault (http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) may be more appropriate for this kind of question. Unless you already executed `top` as root you can try `sudo top` to get more insight. But even then, the instance has to handle I/Os (network, disks, etc) that you don't see in top, so the actual load of the virtual CPU can be higher than the load you see inside the virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks, konqi. I will give serverfault a try. I still think 40% seems like an awful lot for a "idle" instance...

Comment: In my case, the culprit was Docker 1.13.1. Get out of that version https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31060

Answer (score 0):

`top` gives a momentary measure (I believe every second?), while the Console's data might be over a longer period of time during which the site had higher activity. With a micro instance, it seems plausible that relatively normal amounts of traffic could take up a relatively high percentage of the CPU, leading to such a metric.